# Calling PhoneStateListener in a thread inside a service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, runnable, android-thread

I'm developing a music app that uses a service to play the songs in the background. Inside my service I have a code for listening the phone state and pausing the music if a call comes in and then playing it again after the call finishes.

This code works fine inside onCreate but when I put it inside a Thread it gives:
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference*

**What I tried**: I tried to put a Looper.prepare inside the code. This prevented it from crashing but when a phone call comes, the song doesn't stop. I guess I didn't use Looper function right.

```
final class phoneStateThread implements Runnable
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {


                Log.v(TAG,"Starting telephony");
                telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Log.v(TAG,"Starting listener");
                phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        Log.v(TAG,"Starting CallStateChange");
                        switch (state){

                            //=====Phone ringing. Pause music=====
                            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                                if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
                                    pauseMedia();
                                    isPausedInCall=true;
                                }

                                break;

                            //=====Phone idle. start music=====
                            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                                if(mediaPlayer!=null){
                                    if(isPausedInCall){
                                        isPausedInCall=false;
                                        playMedia();
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                };


                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code works fine inside onCreate

Because it using Looper of `Android Main Thread`, when you put your code into `Thread`, `Looper` not available there, you need make your own `Looper`. Try this

```
final class phoneStateThread implements Runnable
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {

                Looper.prepare()
                Log.v(TAG,"Starting telephony");
                telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Log.v(TAG,"Starting listener");
                phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                        Log.v(TAG,"Starting CallStateChange");
                        switch (state){

                            //=====Phone ringing. Pause music=====
                            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                                if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
                                    pauseMedia();
                                    isPausedInCall=true;
                                }

                                break;

                            //=====Phone idle. start music=====
                            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                                if(mediaPlayer!=null){
                                    if(isPausedInCall){
                                        isPausedInCall=false;
                                        playMedia();
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                        }

                    }

                };


                telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                Looper.loop()
            }
        }
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. I tried putting Looper.loop() before the telephonymanager.listen . I guess that was the problem.